# Where can we download previous revisions of the Android Support library?

Tags: android

I'm in need to get previous revisions of the Android Support Lib since there have been a couple weird issues introduced on the last two revisions 8, 9.  I want to compare the source to figure out what could have happened and maybe patch it myself.

Essentially the issue is with the ViewPager not measuring correctly its width when used by a custom ViewGroup. Leaving the edge showing the next page slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some (jar with source and javadoc) in [Maven Central Repository](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C-1026250933).

Android Support Library is open source, you can directly check the source in GitHub project [android/platform_frameworks_support](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support). for instance, [android.support.v4.view.ViewPager](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) and click <kbd>History</kbd> at the top right corner of java code to see [the complete change history](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/commits/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it [here](http://qdevarena.blogspot.com/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) maybe. If not, I do not think they publish the link for the older versions.

However, you can still see what changes were made [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Notes). If that is not enough, ask a new question about the issue with ViewGroup and we will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can find these support libraries at the Google download site:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android
```

- [Revision 8](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r08.zip)
- [Revision 9](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r09.zip)