# Android Support Library Direct Link for Downloading

Tags: android

Is there any direct link for downloading Android support library version 8?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435076/where-can-we-download-previous-revisions-of-the-android-support-library

Answer (score 34):

Although unpublished, the older versions (back to support_r04.zip) seems to be still available from the download site at the same directory for the latest one (support_r10.zip) [as specified in the addon.xml](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/addon.xml).

So for R8, the URL is https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r08.zip

Answer (score 15):

[Joe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12518544/1908296) is Correct answer.

**In General** this [Android Official page](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) list all Android Support Library Just Choose your Library version and Use Google repository Url:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/
```

Example:

for Android Support Library revision 19 :

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.zip
```

for Android Support Library revision 19.0.1 :

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.0.1.zip
```

for Android Support Library revision 19.1.0 :

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip
```

**Notice** The Oldest Android Support Library You can Download Like [Joe answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12518544/1908296) Is Android Support Library revision 4 :

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r04.zip
```

Comment: Can I download Android Support Library revision 24?

Comment: @Gaurang the last version is 23 -> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r23.zip But version 24 not exists given 404 -> https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r24.zip

Answer (score 0):

An almost complete list of android SDK and other needed tools even instructing materials exist in the following link. Download what you want and unzip them into your android SDK home:
http://downloads.puresoftware.org/files/android/

This can be useful for those that have download problems with SDK Manager or cause of Google sanctions against some countries or etc.

Answer (score 0):

for Android Support Library revision 20.0.0 :

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r20.zip

for Android Support Library revision 21.0.0 :

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r21.zip