# How to force Eclipse project to use an older version of the support library

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle, android-appcompat

I know I know I should be using Android Studio, but I can't for some reasons.

So is there a way to force Eclipse to use an older version of the support library for a project.

For example in Android Studio, we can do that by the `22.2.1` part in the build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
```

Comment: Step #1: Recover, from your backups if need be, the Eclipse project for `appcompat-v7` reflecting the version that you seek. Step #2: Use that project.

Comment: "Recover, from your backups" - are those backups automatically stored somewhere?

Comment: @Solace YOUR backups are stored where YOU put them, if YOU didn't make backups of YOUR project YOU don't have backups

Comment: @tyczj CommonsWare said, "Recover, from your backups if need be, **the Eclipse project for appcompat-v7** ". They are talking about the `appcompat-v7` project, not MY project.

Comment: @Solace same still applies, if you didnt make backups of the appcompat library you dont have backups. the library gets overridden everytime you update it

Comment: @tyczj I don't know anyone who would sit and create back ups of the things in the sdk. That's why it's hard for me to believe that is meant here.

Comment: "I don't know anyone who would sit and create back ups of the things in the sdk" -- talented developers have solid backup regimens for their developer machine. That being said, if you can download the AAR from JCenter or Maven Central, you can take a shot at [converting it back into an Android library project for use with Eclipse](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download specific compatibility lib from dl-ssl.google.com repository, described in here: [Android Support Library Direct Link for Downloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518002/android-support-library-direct-link-for-downloading)

Specifically guess/construct your version here:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/support_r19.1.zip

Unzip and import as existing source into eclipse.

Check to install according Android SDK Build-tools in the Android ASK manager.

Answer (score 3):

The only option is to find the old version of appcompat-v7, add it (including the sources or jars and all resources) as a library project into your Eclipse workspace and then make your project use/import that library.

Comment: " find the old version of appcompat-v7, add it (including the sources or jars and all resources)" Does that mean I can download the old version manually, place it somewhere outside the sdk (or inside it, just anywhere for that matter) and import it just like normally import appcompat-v7 from the sdk and use in my project?

Comment: @Solace It means that you can import the appcompat from the sdk folder. You will find all versions here.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti AFA I am aware, sdk contains only the one version which has been downloaded using sdk manger.