# Download previous revision of Android sources using SDK Manager

Tags: android, sdk

I'd like to download sources for Android SDK API 15 Revision 1. Android SDK Manager allows downloading only the latest revision - Revision 2. How can I download sources that I want?

I've tried downloading it from
http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/
but I can't find any link to download Android sources.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot download previous versions using SDK manager

Comment: do you know any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Android is an open source project, you can check [github](https://github.com/android) and use history to see what changes are made to each java files. I use this tecknique and I guess it is the only option.

Good Luck!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442109/2741586