# Retrieve Android API 19 Libraries?

Tags: android, api, android-4.4-kitkat

I had just updated my app to use Androids API 21 from 19, but the app failed to run as it noted that many of the methods have been deprecated. As there is very little documentation for API 21, given it is so new, I then switched to switch my app back to API 19. However, given the main reference libraries have also been updated: `android-support-v4` and `android-support-v4-appcompat` and therefore logcat lists the error upon running when I attempt to switch my app back to API 19:

```
Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
  C:\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
```

**Is there a way to undo the changes of an API update or simply migrate back to a previous API? Or perhaps a location to download those API 19 versions of the libraries?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can we download previous revisions of the Android Support library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435076/where-can-we-download-previous-revisions-of-the-android-support-library)

Answer (score -1):

Source code control (SCC) (such as SVN, Git, Mercurial) is the best way to enable the ability to revert code and libraries to previous versions. Unfortunately, you can only go back in source if you were using SCC at the point you want to revert to.

In your case, downloading archived versions of the library is the best way to solve your problem this time. There are several places you can download these, but Google search of "android support library archive" is your friend, or see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11442109/2291).

Comment: Where are some sources, I can only find Revision 18